# CM4 USB 3.0 Peripheral/Gadget Mode

Tags: usb3, gadget, compute-module-4, pci

The CM4 can be a USB 2.0 peripheral using OTG, but USB 3.0 (or higher) is not natively supported by the Broadcom chip. For the Raspberry Pi 4 Model B+, the VL805-Q6 chip provides USB 3.0 host ports over PCIe, but not in peripheral/gadget mode. Are there any similar methods for providing USB 3.0 peripheral capabilities on the CM4?

The PLX USB 3380/[3382](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/12351863) chips seem to be the perfect solution; they provide upstream or downstream PCIe Gen 2 ports and a USB 3.0 peripheral port. The 3382 chip seems like it could even be daisy-chained to provide two USB 3.0 peripheral ports (e.g., imagine a CM4 acting as a webcam for two PCs). Unfortunately, these chips are obsolete. I'm also not sure what level of support for these chips is available in the Linux kernel. Are there any modern alternatives?